# Deletando imagens com PHP

Tags: php, imagem, diretório, delete

Estou trabalhando em uma cloud pessoal para minha namorada pois o iCloud dela está cheio.

Basicamente é isto que está fazendo tudo funcionar:

```
<?php
$dirname = "uploads/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE);

usort($images, create_function('$b,$a', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
foreach($images as $image) {

echo '
 <a href="'.$image.'">
 <img class="img-grid" src="'.$image.'" />
 </a>';
}

?>
```

[image: E é assim que se parece]

Tudo funciona perfeitamente porém preciso bolar um jeito de que apareça um botão ou algo do tipo próximo às imagens (ou até dentro da imagem) para que ela possa apagar a imagem que precisar.

Vale lembrar que ela usa em sua maioria pelo **smartphone**, tendo necessidade de ser algo fácil de ser executado no touchscreen. Sei também que o ideal seria usar o unlink(), porém não sei como fazer ele funcionar. Sou novo com PHP.

De início pensei na solução abaixo, mas aceito qualquer ideia!
(Ao clicar, aparecer uma pop-up OU redirecionar para uma página da imagem em que ela possa ser apagada)

[image: Click open]

Comment: Tua dificuldade está em criar a funcionalidade para excluir a imagem ou adicionar o botão de exclusão da forma demonstrada?

Comment: Os dois! Tentei várias vezes e sem sucesso, inclusive acabei deletando o o diretório inteiro de uploads sem querer uma vez

Comment: Já que vc é novo no PHP, porque ao invés de ficar se matando, você não colocar um gereciador de imagens gratuito no seu servidor, veja [esse aqui](http://freewebfilemanager.com/filemanager/) ou [esse aqui](http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/) ou [esse aqui](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/)

Comment: Mas a intenção é aprimorar meus conhecimentos amigo rs

Comment: Você irá aprimorar seu conhecimento usando biblioteca de terceiros. Muito mais do que fazendo tudo sozinho sem herdar nenhum conhecimento.

Comment: Mas de qualquer jeito preciso de uma interface amigável, é minha namorada que está usando, nem preciso dessa cloud, isso que é f*da :/

Comment: Mas de qualquer forma, para fazer um botão de exclusão é muito simples, dá até pra fazer um hover ao passar o mouse... e colocar uma ação nesse botão. e apagar usando ajax.

Comment: Aqui é [um exemplo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ivanferrer/9gqaqaoL/) que fiz usando somente javascript.

Comment: Na verdade pensando melhor o botão de exclusão na imagem/ao lado da imagem seria algo inviável, tendo em vista que ela usa apenas no smartphone e as imagens ficam muito pequenas na tela, o que pode levar à um miss click. Talvez eu tenha mais trabalho do que estou pensando.

Comment: Atualizei a ideia no post.

Comment: Por enquanto fiz um exemplo do botão, assim que puder respondo completo. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andradeasmarcelo/jkuvhaw1/1/)